# Stop scrolling to every clicked link one after one, scroll just to the first clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I need to fix my code. If I will click on more than one html href link in menu my script will scroll to every one clicked link one after one clicked links. I need to scroll just to the first clicked link and another clicked links during the scrolling function will be ignored.

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function () {
var hash = window.location.hash;

hash = hash.replace("#", "");

var elem = jQuery(".pb-line-css-group-" + hash);

menu_scroll_to(elem);
});

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery(".menu-item A").click(function () {
    var hash = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    hash = hash.replace("#", "");
    hash = hash.replace("/", "");

    var elem = jQuery(".pb-line-css-group-" + hash);

    menu_scroll_to(elem);
});
});

function menu_scroll_to(elem) {

if (elem) {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: elem.offset().top - 70
    }, 2000, "easeOutQuint");
}

}
```

Comment: Create a variable var=0 check if var==1 don't scroll so make an increase in this if block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a debounce function so that you only call menu_scroll_to() one time for multiple clicks within a set period of time.

Here is a link to a debounce function that should work.

[Debounce function](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

add that function to your JS and replace the following line:

```
menu_scroll_to(elem);
```

with:

```
debounce(function() {
    menu_scroll_to(elem);
}, 250);
```

where 250 is the time in milliseconds.

final code all together would be something like this:

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function () {
        var hash = window.location.hash;

        hash = hash.replace("#", "");

        var elem = jQuery(".pb-line-css-group-" + hash);

        menu_scroll_to(elem);
});

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery(".menu-item A").click(function () {
                var hash = jQuery(this).attr('href');

                hash = hash.replace("#", "");
                hash = hash.replace("/", "");

                var elem = jQuery(".pb-line-css-group-" + hash);

                debounce(function () {
                    menu_scroll_to(elem);
                }, 250);
        });
});

function menu_scroll_to(elem) {
    if (elem) {
            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: elem.offset().top - 70
            }, 2000, "easeOutQuint");
    }
};

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Comment: If I unerstand I need to add this code

              function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
   var timeout;
   return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
     timeout = null;
     if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
   };
  };

and then use this?
debounce(function() {
    menu_scroll_to(elem);
}, 250);